# SELECT COUNT(id) running slower than other counts in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL Workbench 8.0 and MySQL Server 8.0. I have a DB with 8.5 Million rows and the query

```
SELECT COUNT (id)
FROM table
```

takes about 14 seconds.

If I run instead, on the same table,

```
SELECT COUNT (id)
FROM table
WHERE id > 0
```

(as there are no zero or negative id) runs in 2.5 seconds. It happens even if I restart the Workbench and run the second query first.

Is there anything I should adjust in the settings to prevent the first query to run that slow?

Comment: If you like to count all items in the table use COUNT(*) then the database knows you do not care about the ID field.

Comment: Is it the same table on both cases? What version of Mysql are you using? How many rows does the table have? Is the "id" column indexed? Is the id column the primary key? Does negative ids exist?

Comment: Thank you. Running SELECT COUNT(id) or SELECT COUNT(*) results in the same execution time.

Comment: Is the ID field nullable? If so, change it to NOT NULL.

Comment: Incidentally, it's odd to have a column called id that isn't indexed, and a table without any index (arguably) isn't really a table.

Comment: Thanks, Not Null, Unsigned, Auto Incremental

Comment: Please, attach the table definition. Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table-name>`

Comment: Are you sure that the 14 seconds is not for the `> 0` query? That would make sense...

Comment: I am positive 14S is the duration tiime for the query without the WHERE clause